# indent line or selected region or whole document in visual studio 2010 C# with resharper

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, indentation

It seems like none of the settings for indentation are working for me. Tried 
CTRl-K,Ctrl-F
Ctrk-K,Ctrl-D
Ctrl-I

I don't want to move to the beginning of the line for every indent using tab. Is there a set of commands that will work in my visual studio C# 2010 with Resharper, that will accomplish indenting line, selected region or whole document?

thanks

Comment: This is not clear. What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: If *all* you're trying to do is indent your code then you can select your code and press the tab key.

Answer (score 0):

You can format the selection with `Ctrl+E, F` and the whole document with `Ctrl+E, D`.

Doing this should tidy up any missing/incorrect indents you may have.

**Edit**

You can find these in Visual Studio by going to Edit -> Advanced. Format Document and Format Selection should be the first two items in the list.

Comment: None of these work. Can you please tell me the command name for these commands so I can search for it in key mappings? thx

Answer (score 0):

With Resharper, the correct command is Ctrl+Alt+F (Code cleanup) that can you can use to do a number of cleanups including indenting for selection or document

Answer (score 0):

Change the background color to another color other than the page background (I used silver on a white main background) and it will give it that indented feel that you are looking for.

`Options` > `Environment` > `Fonts and Colors` > Display Items: `Preprocessor Keyword` and then change the `item background` dropdown.